# What does ```treat_info_as_error``` do in Alpha Vantage python module

Tags: alpha-vantage

For the alpha-vantage python module, does anyone know what the argument `treat_info_as_error` does?

This is what I found in terms of documentation. It's not much.

> TimeSeries
>   Definition : TimeSeries(key=None, output_format='json', treat_info_as_error=True, indexing_type='date', >proxy=None)
>
> This class implements all the api calls to times series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run an almost invalid API call on Alpha Vantage you'll get a key in the JSON response that says "note" or "Information" or something like that. This parameter is whether or not you want to treat those in your code as an error.

For some reference, here [is a link to the docs](https://alpha-vantage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/alpha_vantage.html).

For example, if you hit an API call threshold, or use the "demo" API key for calls other than what they are suited for.

Try this API call:
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=TSLA&interval=5min&apikey=demo

You'll see it says "Information" as the first key.